# Macros as values in C char array

Tags: c, macros

I need to initialize a char array with macros as it's values.
I've tried to do it like this:

```
    char    text[][255] = {
     "",
    /*  1 */        MACRO_("Foobar","Some text to translate"),
    /*  2 */        MACRO_("Foobar","Some more text to translate"),
//...
};
```

But I get this error:

> error: initializer element is not constant

I think the compiler can't resolve the macro.
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What is the macro definition?

Comment: What is the definition of MACRO_ ?

Comment: MACRO_ calls a function which translates the text. It's not my solution but I have to work with it :(

Answer (score 2):

It is more likely that `MACRO()` is expanding to something non-constant, such as a function call to look up a translation. That's at least what is usually done in situations like those.

With [GNU gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), which also uses macros to mark and look upstrings for translation, you use a separate marking-only macro for situations like these (typically called `N_()`), then you pass the string to the run-time macro `_()` before using it.

You can't initialize an array with data that requires a function call in order to be computed, it must be constant data.

Comment: I already know that I can't, but I still need to have this array. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @user2091046 the classic workaround is to put untranslated text in the array, and call the translation macro where the array is used.

Answer (score 0):

`> MACRO_ calls a function which translates the text. It's not my solution but I have to work with it`

The fact is that you can not initialize your array at *compile time* with data coming from `MACRO_` since it calls a function. However all is not lost. You can simply do this during *run time*

ex:

```
#define MACRO_ ...//whatever it does

int main()
{
   char    text[10][255] = {0}; // you'll have to set that first value

   strcpy(text[0],  MACRO_("Foobar","Some text to translate"));
   strcpy(text[1],  MACRO_("Foobar","Some more text to translate"));
   ...
```

Depending on your code, and what `MACRO_` does, and what you're passing in, you might be able to do this in a loop which will save you some writing, but that will solve your problem.